# Pandas multiIndex: add new indexes for each existing index

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    ID  Type
0   a1   y
1   a1   y
2   a2   y
3   a2   n
4   a3   n
```

I want to re-index it to look like this:

```
ID  Subindex Type
a1   1        y
     2        y
a2   1        y
     2        n
a3   1        n
```

Any command in pandas that could do this? Thank you so  much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To number the items in each group, use `cumcount`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['a1', 'a1', 'a2', 'a2', 'a3'], 
                   'Type': ['y', 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n']})
df['Subindex'] = df.groupby('ID').cumcount()+1
print(df)
```

yields

```
   ID Type  Subindex
0  a1    y         1
1  a1    y         2
2  a2    y         1
3  a2    n         2
4  a3    n         1
```